# Wordpress Image size Issue

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a issue, it started when i uploaded my project. When i was working in my local environment everithing was fine.

[Local Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsINX.jpg)

[After Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGDTF.png)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen due to the conflict in css or any other plugin is overwriting the image size of your theme. So first assured if there is any css that is not letting your image to extend in full width, if not then it's 100% [image size issue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

Hope it helps
Thanks

Comment: I notice this: 
https://vivekuelap.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/huamanpata870x450-360x240.jpg

The correct way should be: 
https://vivekuelap.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/huamanpata870x450.jpg
I dont know why is this really happening. Where this -360x240 route come from :/

Comment: Cool, so there is image size issue, now you have to find the the code which is displaying that image...

Comment: It is not weird that only happens in production environment? It worked good on my local